# Creating a custom Recycler list View with Various UI components in one list item

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a created a list view using the recycler view for the Item list.Each list has movie names having these fields :

```
Price (text view - values ranging from 20-100)
Genere (radio button - U/A or spinner)
Availability (text view, values ranging from 10-1000)
duration (spinner - 1/2/3/4 hours or drop down)
Documentary ( radio button - true,false)
feature1 (some UI element to take input values)
feature2 (some UI element to take input values)
feature3(some UI element to take input values)
```

Each list item may or may not have all the fields.
If i implement it using the recycler view each list will have these fields . How can I customize it to make these fields VISIBLE and GONE depending on the Movie types.

This is my text_row_item.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/element_text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This is my recycler_view_frag.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--<RadioGroup-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:gravity="center_horizontal"-->
        <!--android:orientation="horizontal"-->
        <!--android:checkedButton="@+id/linear_layout_rb">-->
        <!--<RadioButton android:id="@+id/linear_layout_rb"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:text="@string/linear_layout_manager"/>-->
    <!--</RadioGroup>-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <!--<RadioGroup-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:gravity="center_horizontal"-->
        <!--android:orientation="horizontal"-->
        <!--android:checkedButton="@+id/linear_layout_rb">-->
        <!--<RadioButton android:id="@+id/linear_layout_rb"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:text="@string/linear_layout_manager"/>-->
    <!--</RadioGroup>-->

</LinearLayout>
```

This is activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/sample_main_layout">

    <ViewAnimator
          android:id="@+id/sample_output"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0px"
          android:layout_weight="1">

        <ScrollView
              style="@style/Widget.SampleMessageTile"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                  style="@style/Widget.SampleMessage"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_page_margin"
                  android:paddingRight="@dimen/horizontal_page_margin"
                  android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_page_margin"
                  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_page_margin"
                  android:text="@string/intro_message" />
        </ScrollView>

        <fragment
              android:name="com.example.android.common.logger.LogFragment"
              android:id="@+id/log_fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </ViewAnimator>

    <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But i am gettign some wierd GUI as attached : 
[image]

What part to look for the correction?

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you may solve it.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
   private ArrayList<Movie> movies;
    public MyAdapter (ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
       this.movies=movies;
     }
class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
    public ViewHolder0(View itemView){
    ...
    }
}

class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
    public ViewHolder1(View itemView){
    ...
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if(movies.get(position).getType()=="brand1"){
      return 0;

    }
    else{
     return 1;

    }

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
         case 1: return new ViewHolder1(...);
         ...
     }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            ViewHolder0 viewHolder0 = (ViewHolder0)holder;
            ...
            break;

        case 1:
            ViewHolder1 viewHolder1 = (ViewHolder1)holder;
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

}